# Spring boot application using Set<> persistentSet exception

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, cascade, hibernate-cascade

i am having issues while trying to get Set<> Collection from the DataBase.
this is the relevant part of the code:

```java
@Entity

public Class User { 
    ... 

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<User> userFriends;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<FriendRequest> friendRequests;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<FriendRequest> sentRequests;
}
```

i tried to change the cascade to CascadeType.Persist and still having the same problem. 
if anybody knows the problem i would also be happy to understand what i've been doing wrong and the difference between the CascadeTypes(at least when to use each one).

this is the StackTrace i am getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySet.iterator(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashSet.iterator(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:328)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at MyRally1.demoRally.beans.User.toString(User.java:191)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:328)
```

Thank you !

Comment: Can you add your stacktrace to the post? And the relevant part where you are trying to fetch records

Comment: You have a recursive call somewhere. What happens in your method "MyRally1.demoRally.beans.User.toString(User.java:191)"?

Comment: i think the problem is that the Set<> of userFriends contains User Entity, and each one of them contains another Set<> of users (userFriends) and so on, and i think this is the recursive call you mentioned.. i remember working on different project and using @JsonIgnore on the Set<>, but nothing helps here.